# Pulling Data from JSON file coded in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I've pieced the below together from various articles and tutorials but I'm very very new to PHP, JSON, and Javascript.

I have a div with id "playerName" that I need to update every 10 seconds.

**Questions:**

1) I'm doing it "right" or is there an easier way?
2) If I want to update 2 different divs with different values from the JSON file do I just duplicate the full "ajax_get_json" function?

My json file (aka: data.php):

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json"); // set the content type to json
$jsonData = '{
    "u1":{ "name":"Bob", "age":"25", "country":"United States" }
}';
echo $jsonData;
?>
```

My html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ajax_get_json(){
    // Create our XMLHttpRequest object
    var results = document.getElementById("playerName");
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
    hr.open("GET", "data.php", true);
    // Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    // Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
            results.innerHTML = "";
            for(var obj in data) {
                results.innerHTML += data[obj].name;
                setTimeout(ajax_get_jsonStatus, 10000);
            }
        }
    }
    // Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
    hr.send(null); // Actually execute the request
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="playerName"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    ajax_get_json();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm almost over my head and buried in google searches. Any help is appreciated!

Most of the code has come from Adam Khoury's tutorial series: https://youtu.be/wbB3lVyUvAM

Comment: `setTimeout(ajax_get_jsonStatus, 10000);`, where's your `ajax_get_jsonStatus()` function? And why are you using `setTimeout()` function in each iteration of `for` loop?

Answer (score 0):

Avoid building json by hand, it error prone just encode your native data type into json

```
$data = [
    "u1"=>[ "name"=>"Bob", "age"=>"25", "country"=>"United States" ]
];
echo json_encode($data);
```

Don't set the content type header for GET requests, you can't actually a content body in a GET request(via XMLHttpRequest). You may be mixing up the response content type with the request?
There is a value you can set for what you expect the response to be, its `responseType`.

If you want to update more divs just put the data to do it in the response.

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json"); // set the content type to json
$data = [
    "u1"=>[ "name"=>"Bob",    "age"=>"25", "country"=>"United States" ],
    "u2"=>[ "name"=>"Marley", "age"=>"11", "country"=>"of Jamaica" ]
];
echo json_encode($data);
```

```
function ajax_get_json(){
    // Create our XMLHttpRequest object
    var results1 = document.getElementById("player1Name");
    var results2 = document.getElementById("player2Name");
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
    hr.open("GET", "data.php", true);
    // Set response type so the browser knows what to expect and parses it for you
    hr.responseType = 'json';
    // Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var data = this.response;
            results1.innerHTML = data['u1'].name;
            results2.innerHTML = data['u1'].name;
            setTimeout(ajax_get_jsonStatus, 10000);
        }
    }
    // Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
    hr.send(null); // Actually execute the request
}
```